# export to excel in jquery or jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) where I get data at once from server (java) in JSON format. I want the data in the jqGrid to be exported into Excel format.

Till now I saw this [page](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v212tis2.htm) which gives me an error in IE `'o.url is null or not an object' grid.import.js`

Also I saw [this demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/functionality/excel/default.php) where on the tool tip of export button it says `Export To Excel` but the file saved is in xml format.

So I would like any suggestions that can either transform my JSON string into excel using javascript or jquery plugin or using jqgrid's inbuilt feature.

My jqGrid

[image]

My jqGrid Code

```
grid = jQuery("#list2");
                grid.jqGrid({
                    datastr : comparePatchData,
                    datatype: 'jsonstring',
                    colNames:['Name',starheader, header1, header2],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'elementName',index:'elementName', width:90},
                        {name:'isPrasentinXml1',index:'isPrasentinXml1', width:100, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent},
                        {name:'isPrasentinXml2',index:'isPrasentinXml2', width:100, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent},
                        {name:'isPrasentinXml3',index:'isPrasentinXml3', width:100, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent}
                    ],
                    pager : '#gridpager2',
                    rowNum:12,
                    scrollOffset:0,
                    height: 320,
                    autowidth:true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    loadonce:true,
                    jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false,
                        page: function() { return 1; },
                        root: "response"
                    },
                    subGrid: true,
                    // define the icons in subgrid
                    subGridOptions: {
                        "plusicon"  : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                        "minusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                        "openicon"  : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                        //expand all rows on load
                        "expandOnLoad" : false
                    },

                    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                        //console.info(subgrid_id+", "+row_id);
                        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id, iData = -1;
                        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                        //pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
                        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' style='overflow-y:auto' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");

                        $.each(comparePatchData.response,function(i,item){
                            if(item.id === row_id) {
                                iData = i;
                                return false;
                            }

                        });
                        if (iData == -1) {
                            return; // no data for the subgrid
                        }

                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                            datastr : comparePatchData.response[iData],
                            datatype: 'jsonstring',
                            colNames: ['Name','Value1','Value2','Value3'],
                            colModel: [
                                {name:"name",index:"name",width:90},
                                {name:"firstValue",index:"firstValue",width:100},
                                {name:"secondValue",index:"secondValue",width:100},
                                {name:"thirdValue",index:"thirdValue",width:100}
                            ],
                            rowNum:10,
                            //pager: pager_id,
                            sortname: 'name',
                            sortorder: "asc",
                            height: 'auto',
                            autowidth:true,
                            jsonReader: {
                                repeatitems: false,
                                //page: function() { return 1; },
                                root: "attribute"
                            }
                        });

                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
                    }
                });
                grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager2',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
                grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#gridpager2',{
                    caption:"Export to Excel", 
                    onClickButton : function () { 
                        jQuery("#list2").excelExport();
                    } 
                });
```

Part of my Json

```
{
"response": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "elementName": "libgtop2-devel-2.14.4-3.el5",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": false,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "thirdValue": "libgtop2-devel-2.14.4-3.el5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "elementName": "ifd-egate-0.05-15",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": false,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "thirdValue": "ifd-egate-0.05-15"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "elementName": "libXScrnSaver-devel-1.1.0-3.1",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": false,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "thirdValue": "libXScrnSaver-devel-1.1.0-3.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "elementName": "kde-i18n-Chinese-Big5-3.5.4-1",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "kde-i18n-Chinese-Big5-3.5.4-1",
                "secondValue": "kde-i18n-Chinese-Big5-3.5.4-1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "elementName": "cpio-2.6-20",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "cpio-2.6-20",
                "secondValue": "cpio-2.6-20",
                "thirdValue": "cpio-2.6-20"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "elementName": "grep-2.5.1-54.2.el5",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "grep-2.5.1-54.2.el5",
                "secondValue": "grep-2.5.1-54.2.el5",
                "thirdValue": "grep-2.5.1-54.2.el5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "elementName": "avahi-compat-libdns_sd-0.6.16-1.el5",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "avahi-compat-libdns_sd-0.6.16-1.el5",
                "secondValue": "avahi-compat-libdns_sd-0.6.16-1.el5",
                "thirdValue": "avahi-compat-libdns_sd-0.6.16-1.el5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "elementName": "gpm-devel-1.20.1-74.1",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "gpm-devel-1.20.1-74.1",
                "secondValue": "gpm-devel-1.20.1-74.1",
                "thirdValue": "gpm-devel-1.20.1-74.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "elementName": "esc-1.0.0-39.el5",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": false,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "thirdValue": "esc-1.0.0-39.el5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "elementName": "kde-i18n-Spanish-3.5.4-1",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "kde-i18n-Spanish-3.5.4-1",
                "secondValue": "kde-i18n-Spanish-3.5.4-1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580261/how-to-get-all-ids-of-jqgrid-including-the-paginated-ones/6581791#6581791) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724342/jqgrid-export-to-csv-post-rather-than-get/5759889#5759889) for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to export a file using the Excel format in order to get the data into Excel. It is generally much easier to export to `CSV`. `CSV` files should be associated with Excel by default, so it should have the Excel icon by it and everything. `XML` would work the same way, I think, but the `CSV` format is much lighter, and does the same job in this case. Converting `JSON` to `CSV` is simple:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseJSON).response;
var csv = arrayToCSV(response);

function arrayToCSV(arr) {
    var columnNames = [];
    var rows = [];
    for (var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++) {
        // Each obj represents a row in the table
        var obj = arr[i];
        // row will collect data from obj
        var row = [];
        for (var key in obj) {
            // Don't iterate through prototype stuff
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            // Collect the column names only once
            if (i === 0) columnNames.push(prepareValueForCSV(key));
            // Collect the data
            row.push(prepareValueForCSV(obj[key]));
        }
        // Push each row to the main collection as csv string
        rows.push(row.join(','));
    }
    // Put the columnNames at the beginning of all the rows
    rows.unshift(columnNames.join(','));
    // Return the csv string
    return rows.join('\n');
}

// This function allows us to have commas, line breaks, and double 
// quotes in our value without breaking CSV format.
function prepareValueForCSV(val) {
    val = '' + val;
    // Escape quotes to avoid ending the value prematurely.
    val = val.replace(/"/g, '""');
    return '"' + val + '"';
}
```

Comment: What happens after I have `csv` how do i put it in file?

Comment: That isn't possible to do from the client. You would need to make a server-side script to do that. What are you using on the server?

Comment: Ah. Sadly I don't know java well enough to give a quickie answer on how to make the csv into a file. This javascript function should give you the contents of a csv file in string form, which you can then send to your server-side code to make a file from it on the server.

Comment: Late comment, but I don't fully agree with your remark _equally valuable_. With CSV you have to pay attention to regional settings because of decimal and date formats. With Excel it is possible to work in a type-safe manner.

Comment: @GertArnold True. Removed "equally valuable" claim above.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a jqGrid where I get data at once from server (java) in JSON
>   format. I want the data in the jqGrid to be exported into Excel
>   format.

Here's a nice article, showing you how to export from jqGrid to Excel...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784342/Export-data-from-jqGrid-into-a-real-Excel-file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like this:

1. **Read**

https://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/#Installation

2. Here is **github**

https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin

3. Here is a **demo**

http://demos.w3lessons.info/jquery-table-export#

It works perfectly i tried the **Export Excel**.
In my case i just used the id selector for the jqgrid table.

**BTW** This will export only visible part so if you 100 pages it need server side because info is just not there !.

Answer (score -2):

I'm working with MOSS 2007 to export some lists(say 5 lists) to excel.My requirement is i need more than one lists to be exported to excel.I have added a CEWP in my page with a button so that by one click i can export more than one list datas to excel.nw i get a run time error when i use jquery 
   if( $('#WebPartWPQ3').is(':visible') )--->object expected error.
I dont find any div id to trace..so is anybody know the answer,pls be come out of it..
ans related to this issue is really really really appreciated..my code is as follows.

```
<button type="button"
onclick=exportToExcel();>Click<br>
</button><br>
<script type="text/javascript"><br>
 function exportToExcel() <br>
{ <br>
alert('Hi');<br>
//alert($("#WebPartWPQ3").attr("visibility"));<br>
if( $('#WebPartWPQ3').is(':visible') )<br>
{ <br>
 contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";<br>
var oExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");<br>
var oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add;<br>
var oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1);<br>

var VESSApplications =document.getElementById<br>('ctl00_m_g_e3f5d791_5651_40ca_a03a_1c511c7f2b28_ctl00_ctl00_toolBarTbl');<br>
  alert(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ3'));<br>
var OtherApplications =document.getElementById('tblOtherApplications');<br>
 //   var MFGApplications =document.getElementById('tblMFGApplications');<br>
var row=3;<br>
var col=1;<br>

//Define criteria - start<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col)="Business Function";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+1)="VESS";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+2)=selectedVESSBusinessFunction;<br>
 //  oSheet.Cells(row, col+3)="Manufacturing";<br>
 //  if(selectedMFGBusinessFunction != "-Select-")<br>
 //  oSheet.Cells(row, col+4)=selectedMFGBusinessFunction;<br>
row +=2;<br>

oSheet.Cells(row, col)="Operating System";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+1)="First Choice";<br>
    if(selectedOperatingSystemFirstChoice != "-Select-")<br>

 oSheet.Cells(row, col+2)=selectedOperatingSystemFirstChoice;<br>


oSheet.Cells(row, col+3)="Second Choice";<br>

if(selectedOperatingSystemSecondChoice != "-Select-")<br>

oSheet.Cells(row, col+4)=selectedOperatingSystemSecondChoice;<br>

row +=2;<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col)="Platform";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+1)="First Choice";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+2)=selectedPlatformFirstChoice;<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+3)="Second Choice";<br>

if(selectedPlatformSecondChoice != "-Select-")<br>

oSheet.Cells(row, col+4)=selectedPlatformSecondChoice;<br>
row +=2;<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col)="Delivery Method";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+1)="First Choice";<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+2)=selectedDeliveryFirstChoice;<br>
oSheet.Cells(row, col+3)="Second Choice";<br>

 if(selectedDeliverySecondChoice != "-Select-")<br>

oSheet.Cells(row, col+4)=selectedDeliverySecondChoice;<br>
row +=2;<br>
//alert(VESSApplications.rows.length);<br>
if(VESSApplications.rows.length>0)<br>
{<br>
 for (var y = 0; y < VESSApplications.rows.length; y++) <br>
 {<br>
     for (var x = 0; x < VESSApplications .rows(y).cells.length; x++) <br>
     {<br>
   //          oSheet.Cells(y + 1, x + 1) = VESSApplications .rows(y).cells(x).innerText;<br>
         oSheet.Cells(row, x + 1) = VESSApplications .rows(y).cells(x).innerText;<br>

     }<br>
             row++;<br>

 }<br>
 //   oExcel.Visible = true;<br>
  // oExcel.UserControl = true;<br>
}<br>

else<br>
{<br>
alert("There is no VESS/Other Applications to Export!");<br>
}<br>
row +=2;<br>

//Other Applications<br>

 /*     for (var y = 0; y < OtherApplications.rows.length; y++) <br>
 {<br>
     for (var x = 0; x < OtherApplications.rows(y).cells.length; x++) <br>
     {<br>
         oSheet.Cells(row, x + 1) = OtherApplications.rows(y).cells(x).innerText;<br>

     }<br>
             row++;<br>

 }<br>


   row +=2;<br>


//MFG Applications<br>

 for (var y = 0; y < MFGApplications.rows.length; y++) <br>
 {<br>
     for (var x = 0; x < MFGApplications.rows(y).cells.length; x++) <br>
     {<br>
   //          oSheet.Cells(y + 1, x + 1) = VESSApplications .rows(y).cells(x).innerText;<br>
         oSheet.Cells(row, x + 1) = MFGApplications.rows(y).cells(x).innerText;<br>

     }<br>
             row++;<br>

 }<br>

 */  
oSheet.columns.autofit;<br>


 oExcel.Visible = true;<br>
 oExcel.UserControl = true;<br>
}<br>
else<br>
{<br>
 alert('No VESS/Other applications available to export');<br>
}<br>
}<br>
```