# json or xml to xls or csv (MS Excel) export using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am continuing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742567/export-to-excel-in-jquery-or-jqgrid) I need a way to export my json string into a `xls` or `csv` file that can be opened in MS Excel (I am using simple html and jsp).

So far I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.85).aspx) that made me open a excel using

```
var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    xls.visible = true;
```

Any type of suggestions is welcome. Thankyou

Comment: Not on the client, unless you only want IE support. Ask the server to generate a file and give the client a download link.

Comment: @Raynos: Where can I find out that it will only support IE? do you mean `ActiveXObject` will only support IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with xls format so I can't give a code example, but you can use `handlebars.js` http://www.handlebarsjs.com/ which is a small and simple json -> xml templating engine.

EDIT:

I was under the false impression that xls files were xml. So unless excel has the ability to import xml, you should create the xls server-side with something like this http://pizzaseo.com/php-excel-creator-class. You can do with with ajax to make it transparent to the user.

EDIT:

Excel can import xml files so you can use handlbars.js http://www.handlebarsjs.com/ to easily convert json to xml. However if that's not an option, you should look into POI http://poi.apache.org/ which is a JAVA api for Microsoft documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also I am using java and struts2 on server side

Comment: K I am using POI so I should send the stream to client side! then in client side what should i do?

Comment: You'd create the file on the server, then do something like `window.location = http://yourserver.com/file.xls` once it's done to start the download.