# By using kendo how to export the grid data to any one of the following files (csv,excel ,Pdf)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kendo-ui

I am filling the data into Kendogrid using remote data.So is it possible to export data the data in the grid to any files like csv,excel and pdf using kendoUI.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "odata",
                                    transport: {
                                        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                                    },
                                    schema: {
                                        model: {
                                            fields: {
                                                OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                                Freight: { type: "number" },
                                                ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                                ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    pageSize: 10,
                                    serverPaging: true,
                                    serverFiltering: true,
                                    serverSorting: true
                                },
                                height: 250,
                                filterable: true,
                                sortable: true,
                                pageable: true,
                                columns: [{
                                        field:"OrderID",
                                        filterable: false
                                    },
                                    "Freight",
                                    {
                                        field: "OrderDate",
                                        title: "Order Date",
                                        width: 100,
                                        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                    }, {
                                        field: "ShipName",
                                        title: "Ship Name",
                                        width: 200
                                    }, {
                                        field: "ShipCity",
                                        title: "Ship City"
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: you can read the full datasource using  **$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()**

Comment: this has nothing to do with kendo actually you are generating the data .and you can convert it to any format.

Comment: when ever user clicks the button I need to export the data.I tired like this but no use. $("#download").click(function () {
                    var json = $.parseJSON($("#json").val());
                    var csv = JSON2CSV(json);
                    window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv))
                });

Comment: is it possible to change the file name .Presently I am getting download.xls I want to change this name

Comment: I append the response.Addheader but no use .and It was showing as unexpected identifier error

Answer (score 2):

Kendo UI now supports export to both Excel and PDF. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export

Comment: see also http://developer.telerik.com/featured/exporting-data-ease-using-kendo-ui-grid/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't any built in functionality for exporting the grid.

There is a [code library](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/export-grid-to-excel.aspx) example that demonstrates this if you are using ASP.NET MVC
but I don't know of one if you are not using MVC.  According to some forum answers they do not have plans to build this in which I don't like and hope we as users can vote for this feature.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742567/export-to-excel-in-jquery-or-jqgrid) that may be of help it shows how to export a json response to cvs.

So what you want to do is get the datasource of your grid and call .toJson
Something like this

```
      var mydata= $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().toJson();
```

Then pass that to the function in the link I provided

Also note: you may need to get the view of the datasource if you want to include the filtering and paging, at least I think. view would be dataSource.view()

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes what you said is correct,I are not using MVC,using kendo html web .The kendo provided MVC example also not able to open as it was vs 2013.anyway thanks for responding.

Comment: Just as a side not jqwidgets grid has a function to export to excel  you could take a look at their javascript export function and apply it to kendoUI  http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-grid-export-to-excel

Comment: Ok I have already seen this and they have in built function  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls', 'jqxGrid'); but in kendo I have not found such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

On github I have a project that allows you to download the Grid to a CSV: [Kendo Grid CSV Export](https://github.com/uber-rob/kendo-grid-csv-download)