# Export jqgrid filtered data as excel or CSV

Tags: servlets, jqgrid

I am in trouble please help me out.I want to show "export to excel" button in the pager of jqgrid, that will export the current set of data which is retrieve after searching criteria of jqgrid (based on the current filter). I am using "loadonce:true" setting for my jqgrid.Now I want to export data from local datasource of jqgrid after searching. If it is not possible then how I can able to pass parameters to a server when I click on export button of navigation on which searching criteria need to do. I am using back-end as a servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to implement export of data on the server and just post the current searching filter to the back-end. Full information about the searching parameter defines `postData` parameter of jqGrid. Another boolean parameter of jqGrid `search` define whether the searching filter should be applied of not. You should better ignore `_search` property of `postData` parameter and use `search` parameter of jqGrid.

Format of the information about the searching filter depend on whether use used `multipleSearch: true` option. I personally use it always. In the case the full information about the filter will be placed in one property of the `postData` parameter: `filters` property. The format is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options). The code which gets the information looks like the following

```
var $grid = $("#list"),
    isFilterAreUsed = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'search'),
    filters = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;
```

If you don't use `multipleSearch: true` option you will be not able to use complex filters and the information about the filter will be placed in three properties of the `postData` parameter: `searchField`, `searchOper` and `searchString`.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have done as you specify and It's working now. I have placed your code in **onClickButton** event of my custom navigation button and after getting filter elements I am calling servlet method by ajax which gives excel file.  Thanks for your reply,It saves my lot's of time.

Comment: @Bhagwat: I'm glad to know that I could help you. You are welcome!

Comment: @Oleg: I tried your answer but filters are not passed. I updated Bhagwat question and added testcase

Comment: @Andrus: What you mean under "filters are not passed"? I described only how one can *get* the current `filters` which are used and don't how to pass the information to somewhere. Additionally I don't see that the Bhagwat`s question are changed and I can't see any testcase. You should explain more clear what you mean.

Comment: @Oleg: It looks like by edit is not published, maybe wait for moderaton. I added answer describing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oleg answer it is possible to use

javascript code:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {
        caption: "Excel",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-save",
        onClickButton: function () {
            document.forms['_export']._buffer.value = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
            document.forms['_export'].submit();
        }
    });
```

Index.aspx:

```
<form  id='_export' method="post" action='<%= Url.Action( "Export", "Grid", new { _entity= Model.Name } ) %>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="_buffer" id="_buffer" value="" />
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Export(string _entity, string _sidx, string _sord, string filters ) {
            string where = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters))
            {
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Filters filtersList = serializer.Deserialize<Filters>(filters);
                where = filtersList.FilterObjectSet(entity);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
                where = " TRUE ";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            Response.Write(GetAllData(_entity, _sidx, _sord, where));
            Response.End();
            return View("Index");
}
```

filters parameter in controller has null value. No idea Which is proper way to pass filters and sorting parameters to Export method.

Comment: Why you don't just use jQuery.ajax to post the data to the server? Do you verified with `alert` that `$("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData')` get you the information which you need?

Comment: @Oleg: I need to open excel result in separate tab or prompt user to download xls file. Ajax does not support this.`alert($("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters)` returns
`{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Klient_nimi","op":"cn","data":"emil"}]}
`

Comment: I personally use in the cases direct setting of `window.location` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6581791/315935) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5759889/315935)). For example  `window.location = myServerBaseUrl/Export + '?filters=' + encodeURIComponent(filters);` inside of `onClickButton`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. If Export controller throws excepton it returns error message as json content. Browses shows 'Not found' page in this case. User doesnt see error message.

Comment: In [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501644/315935) I showed how one can define class `HandleJsonExceptionAttribute` used as the replacement of `[HandleError]` attribute. You can place `Export` action in another controller and use HTML and not json content in the case. You can also provide HTML content on error directly in the `Export` action. So I think that you should just change the error reporting in the `Export` action.